# How to find a way to have a form that represent a value of a matrix

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering how to code a form that represents the value of a matrix:

for example, the user have to enter the values of cash that takes three value for min,neutre,max :

```
         min     neutre     max
cash :   3         20       50
shares:  5         10        5
bonds:   10         0        30
```

Comment: show us the code that you have written

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a table with four columns, like `name`, `min`, `neutre` and `max`.
2. Insert all values one by one by row into the table.
3. Bind with table to `DataGrid`.

---

```
 //databind our datatable to our gridview
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

---

Example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Namespaces
You will need to import the following namespace.
C#

```
 using System.Data;
```

VB.Net

```
 Imports System.Data
```

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                            new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)) });
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

VB.Net

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn() {New DataColumn("Id", GetType(Integer)), _
                                               New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)), _
                                               New DataColumn("Country", GetType(String))})
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States")
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India")
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France")
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia")
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but how can I bind the table to Datagrid ?

Comment: //databind our datatable to our gridview
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: Thank you very much but I code in C# can you tell me the lines that differs. Thanks

Comment: It's ok I haven't seen the post at the top thank you very much